# Illegal iphone app for website

Tags: legal

I have a web site and someone had made an iphone app for my site without my permission and selling it. He is using my API without getting permission.

How can i report this to Apple?

EDIT: AFAIK, there's no way to report this to Apple. I blocked all requests from the iphone app.

Comment: Is this *actually* illegal, or do you just not like it? At a base level, this is what APIs are *for*, no? You haven't specified that he's actually infringing your copyright/trademark, or that your terms of use disallow this, for example.

Comment: My terms of use disallow this. My website doesn't have any registered trademarks. How can i let Apple know about this?

Comment: I am sure it isnt 'illegal' but just like merchants you dont have to serve (or the merchants case sell to) them. I don't know if you can get apple to remove the app, you may. But blocking them is a guaranteed solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just block the app? Like "if API gets requested by BAD-APP >redirect to NOT ALLOWED"

Don't allow the iPhone usage of your site.

Answer (score 1):

An iPhone is nothing else than a smaller computer, thus a web browser like any other. It shouldn't make any difference whether he is rendering your data via native API or webkit. It might be also possible to charge for his "browser" regardless what data he is rendering with it.

I am not lawyer but I guess that makes sense. Sure, the copyright issue remains but it should be treated separately from the fact its an iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [Apple forum thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2488321&tstart=73) pointing the claimant at the iTunes support [contact area](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/).

Comment: Doesnt help. The claimant in that thread has said that the support link is not of use.

Answer (score 0):

btw: did you try to contact the app creator before Apple? may he likes to work something out with you like a 50/50 split of app revenue. 
or just tell him he should remove the app from the market otherwise he get sued ...

Comment: I'm positive he cant sue unless his bandwidth cost goes up from the app or if the app is using trademark/something owned by him